# Intermittent requests.exceptions.ConnectionError when posting to tornado HTTP server?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, tornado

This program creates 500 client processes and one Tornado HTTP server. Each client performs one POST to the server. Sometimes I get requests.exceptions.ConnectionError exceptions. I added retry code to compensate. Staggering when the clients start also helps.

I think the `requests` and `tornado` modules should be able to handle this without extra coding. I'm not sure which is responsible.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

import time
import multiprocessing
import random

import requests
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class Client(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, client_id):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.host = 'http://localhost:8888/log'
        self.sample_record = 'x'*300
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        # Wait until top of current 5 sec interval so all clients start together.
        time.sleep(5 - time.time()%5)

        #time.sleep(random.random()) # This seems to eliminate the problem.

        # requests.Session will do keep-alive by default.
        session = requests.Session()
        payload = { 'record': 'x'*300 }
        attempt_count = 0
        while True:
            try:
                response = session.post(self.host, data=payload, timeout=10)
                break
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
                print('Retry: id=', self.client_id)
                attempt_count += 1
                assert attempt_count < 10
                continue
        assert response.status_code == 200 and response.text == 'Success'

post_received_count = 0

class LogHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        global post_received_count
        post_received_count += 1
        if post_received_count%100 == 0:
            print('post count=', post_received_count)
        self.write('Success')

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application(
        [
            (r"/log", LogHandler),      # http://localhost:8888/log
        ],
        cookie_secret = "__TODO:_GENERATE_YOUR_OWN_RANDOM_VALUE_HERE__",
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    time.sleep(6 - time.time()%5)  # Wait until one sec into next 5 sec interval.
    print('Start clients...')
    client_list = [Client(i) for i in range(500)]
    print('Done.')

    app = make_app()
    app.listen(8888)
    try:
        tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

Output from two runs on Linux. No problem on the first run. The program prints the number of POSTs performed. It stops after 500 POSTs. I then use Ctrl-\ to kill the server. Multiple ConnectionError exceptions requiring retries on the second attempt.

It consistently runs without exceptions if I un-comment the `time.sleep(random.random())` statement. That's a random sleep between 0-1 second. Apparently the problem is only when too many clients submit a request at the same time.

```
$ ulimit -n 10000
$ test_log_server.py
Start clients...
Done.
post count= 100
post count= 200
post count= 300
post count= 400
post count= 500
^\Quit (core dumped)
$ test_log_server.py
Start clients...
Done.
post count= 100
Retry: id= 223
Retry: id= 340
Retry: id= 116
Retry: id= 164
Retry: id= 258
Retry: id= 150
Retry: id= 290
Retry: id= 16
Retry: id= 40
Retry: id= 5
post count= 200
post count= 300
post count= 400
post count= 500
^\Quit (core dumped)
$
```

I get the following exceptions if I remove the try block. This is from one of the 500 clients. Other clients reported the same exceptions.

```
Process Client-102:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1373, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 311, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 272, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 639, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 367, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 692, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 601, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 383, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1373, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 311, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 272, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 586, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/process.py", line 258, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "./test_log_server.py", line 31, in run
    response = session.post(self.host, data=payload, timeout=10)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 567, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 520, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 490, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

Comment: What's the exception message?

Comment: @xyres I added the full exceptions to my post.

Comment: So the server is closing the connections. But as this exception is from the client's side, it's hard to tell what's exactly causing this. Could you try and throttle the rate at which you're sending the requests? Maybe a deleay of a few microseconds between requests.

Comment: @xyres I simplified my sample program and updated my post based on your suggestion.

Comment: try to use AsyncHTTPClient in Tornado instead of requests, requests will block the main thread.

Comment: @TomChen The clients are separate processes and are are not running an IOLoop. So AsyncHTTPClient is not required, correct?

Comment: yeah, you're right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Apparently the problem is only when too many clients submit a request at the same time.

500 client processes is a lot. One possibility is the socket listen backlog, which is set to 128 when you use the `app.listen` interface. In older kernel versions 128 was the maximum allowed here, but more recently it's become possible to increase it (depending on your kernel version and other configurations). Try replacing `app.listen(8888)` with:

```
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app)
server.bind(8888, backlog=4096)
server.start()
```

I would also suggest if you really need to support this many connections being initiated at once you'll probably want to run more than one sever process instead of just increasing the socket backlog of a single process.